# Create Trigger that will perform a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to offer some automation to a process already in place that I cannot change. What I have is one table where data is manually keyed by month and year. Each month has 3 rows which are all manually keyed. I have created a trigger to calculate values for the 3 rows that are TOTALS of the breakdown but what I also need that I can't figure out is getting one row to equal the first row minus the second row.

[This screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrNUV.png) shows the rows as they are in the table, what I want to try to do is to get the row that has a REPORT_TYPE of 'Actual' to equal 'Reported'-'Unfounded'. Under the Homicide column, you will see 1 Reported, 1 Unfounded, and 0 Actual which represents the result I want.

This code recreates the table already in existence:

```
CREATE TABLE PARTONETBL
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    MM FLOAT(8) NOT NULL,
    YYYY FLOAT(8) NOT NULL,
    REPORT_TYPE NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    --REPORT TYPES ARE 'REPORTED', 'UNFOUNDED', 'ACTUAL'
    HOMICIDE FLOAT(8) NOT NULL,
    MANSLAUGHTER FLOAT(8) NOT NULL,
    ROBBERYTOTAL FLOAT(8) NOT NULL,
    ROBBERFIREARM FLOAT(8) NOT NULL,
    ROBBERYKNIFE FLOAT(8) NOT NULL,
    ASSAULTOTAL FLOAT(8) NOT NULL,
    ASSAULTFIREARM FLOAT(8) NOT NULL,
    ASSAULTKNIFE FLOAT(8) NOT NULL,
    TOTAL FLOAT(8) NOT NULL
)
```

Here is some sample data to enter into the table:

```
INSERT INTO PARTONETBL(MM, YYYY, REPORT_TYPE, HOMICIDE, MANSLAUGHTER, ROBBERYTOTAL, ROBBERFIREARM, ROBBERYKNIFE, ASSAULTOTAL, ASSAULTFIREARM, ASSAULTKNIFE, TOTAL)
VALUES 
(1, 2022, 'REPORTED', 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 7),
(1, 2022, 'UNFOUNDED', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(1, 2022, 'ACTUAL', 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 7)
```

There will ALWAYS be three rows for each MM and YYYY. The three rows will always have a ReportType of Reported, Unfounded, and Actual.

Any guidance would be appreciated. This is an old database whose structure cannot be changed, unfortunately, so I am trying to work with what I have.

Comment: Why are you using `FLOAT` for `INT` values?

Comment: And please show us your desired results (as formatted text within the question).

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: And what have you tried? A simple aggregation should return you what you are asking.

Comment: And its not clear to me what is being calculated? You say the 3 rows already exist... so where is the data coming from to create the 3 rows automatically?

Comment: Your title says "Create Trigger that will perform a function" and you ask for help with "what I want to try to do is to get the row that has a REPORT_TYPE of 'Actual' to equal 'Reported'-'Unfounded'": the calculation is trivial, but we do not understand at which point it should be executed. What we need to know: how the rows are added e.g. one by one or all together? Are the values for  'Reported' and 'Unfounded' ever updated once they are entered into the database? If yes, should the 'Actual' values be updated as well?

Comment: FWIW you can always handle this when you need to view your data with a query that calculates the Actual based on Report and Unfounded (for instance, in a report or a view or whatever you require).